# im having problems in setting ip address in python socket library

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, messaging

so i want to make a Messenger and i create it with the socket library. by creating a server side and a client side. where two need to be on same internet ( i think so ! )
here is my code:

server side:

```
import socket
import os
os.system('clear')
s = socket.socket()
ip = 'localhost'
port = 9999
s.bind((ip,port))
s.listen()
print ('please wait...')
c , addr =s.accept()
print ('someone has joined!')

class color : 
    GREEN = '\033[92m'
    RED = '\033[91m'
    WHITE = '\033[0m'

while True :
    msg = input(color.RED + 'your message: ' )
    c.send(msg.encode('utf8'))
    print (color.GREEN + c.recv(1024).decode())
```

client side :

```
import socket
import os
os.system('clear')
s=socket.socket()
ip='192.168.1.3'
port=9999
s.connect((ip,port))
print('you have been connected' )
class color :
    GREEN = '\033[92m'
    RED = '\033[91m'
    WHITE = '\033[0m'

while True:
    print (color.RED + s.recv(1024).decode())
    msg = input(color.GREEN + 'your message : ')
    s.send(msg.encode('utf8'))
```

here , i need to set an ip address for each side. i tried all methods but nothing worked.
do you have a recommendation to how to do it ? thanks.

errors on each method :

method 1 : setting server side ip 'local_host' or any other gethostname or gethostbyname :
server side works fine but client side does not connect

method 2 : setting server ip address to something like '192.168.0.3' :
server side makes an error : OSError : [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

edit on main :
the methods you guys recommended give an error on client side :

```
connectionrefusederror: [WinError 10061] no connection could be made 
because the target machine refused it
```

Comment: On server (listening computer): IP = 0.0.0.0 ; on client (connecting computer): IP = server's real IP.

Comment: You should use gethostname and gethostbyname to get the actual ip of your computer, and not the string “localhost”.

Comment: @VPfB can you say where can i get the server's real IP?

Comment: thank you. i figured it out
i'll just have a question for you
will this work if client is not on the same network as the server is ?

Comment: @ParsaAd If there is a route between two hosts, it should work. However don't expect a conection between two private networks (typically with 192.168.X.X addresses) over Internet. Also a firewall may prevent a connection establishment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know if this is correct, but it seems from most of the examples that people use `ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`, which lines up with what I know about sockets in C. So try replacing
`ip = “localhost”` with
`ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`.

As the President recommended, you could also bind to the ip “0.0.0.0” during debugging as it will listen on all interfaces, although this will probably not be an issue.

Comment: During debugging it's much better to bind to "0.0.0.0". This effectively binds to *all* interfaces. After the ability to connect is demonstrated then you can change the code to bind only to the interfaces you intend to allow connections from.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk More likely than not they will not accidentally use the wrong interface. However, I will update my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` does not always pick the correct interface.

Comment: @DanielF True, in my answer I added that you can bind to 0.0.0.0 during debugging to avoid issues with different interfaces.